# How to fix inconsistent shadows on model

Tags: normals, shadows

I have a shadow problem which looks like this:

[image]

Here are what the normals look like:

[image]

And here's how they look when I lift the 'button' from the model.

[image]

How should I go about fixing the shadows in my model?

Comment: You can try to fix it with an inset, or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/